# Swift 4: prepare(for segue:) being called after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swift4

I have 2 VCs: **CouponVC** and **CouponFeedbackVC**.

Coupon VC receives **brand: Brand!** from its parentViewController.
Now I want to pass the **brand.name** to **CouponFeedbackVC**.

CouponVC.swift

```
var brandName: String!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad
    brandName = brand.name
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "couponToFeedBack" {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? CouponFeedbackVC {
            print(brandName)
            vc.brandName = self.brandName
        }
    }
}
```

In CouponFeedbackVC.swift

```
var brandName: String!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")
    print(brandName)
}

 override func awakeFromNib() {
    print(brandName)
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Console Log

```
nil
viewDidLoad
nil
StayUncle
```

awakeFromNib() -> viewDidLoad() -> prepare(for segue:)

I am not accessing any outlets from CouponFeedbackVC.

Why is **prepare(for segue: )** being called after **viewDidLoad()** and **awakeFromNib()**?

Comment: How are you performing segue operation from CouponVC ? Using storyboard push operation OR using performSegueWithIdentifier ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `awakeFromNib` you are referencing `self.view` in order to call `layoutIfNeeded`. This causes the view to be loaded and `viewDidLoad` to be called.

If you remove the call to `self.view.layoutIfNeeded` from `awakeFromNib` then `viewDidLoad` will not be called until after `prepare(for:sender:)`. There is no reason to call `layoutIfNeeded` in `awakeFromNib`.

Answer (score 1):

**viewDidLoad() and awakeFromNib()** is called before **prepare(for segue: )** because for passing data from one view controller to another you have to initialize and allocate the object So when **awakeFromNib** is called, it is guaranteed to have all its outlet and action connections already established and than **viewDidLoad** is called which give assurety the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. Now its ready for passing data from one viewcontroller to another.