# Swift segue negating other functions connected to segue object

Tags: swift, uitableview, segue

In a table view controller, I'm trying to get the index of the row that is selected before I segue (will pass this info in prepare for segue eventually). I have implemented this function:

```
var selectedQuestionCell: IndexPath?

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedQuestionCell = indexPath
}
```

This was working great for me initially. I was able to snag the index of the selected row in my table. However, I want to perform a segue when a row is tapped which will transfer to another View. I connected a segue to my cell (dynamic prototypes). After connecting a segue, my override function no longer executes! I'm really new to Table View Controllers, so I'm not sure if there's anyway I can manually execute this.

**To summarize:** my problem is after connecting a segue to my cells, the override function to get their index is no longer called. How can I fix this?

Comment: You can use `pushViewController` without using segue, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24038621/5523205

Comment: check if this helps,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617760/swift-4-preparefor-segue-being-called-after-viewdidload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these thing

Create a new `segue` from your `tableview` to `another view` and name it as you like.

Now add this code inside your `didSelectRowAt`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "your_segue_name_here") as! YourViewControllerName
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    }
```

Please make sure that your `tableview` is connected with `navigation` controller.

To do that select your `tableView` then click on `Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller` from your Xcode.

I hope it works for you.

: D